Is there a way to implement D3.js in Odoo?
I have managed to make some charts using d3.js but I wanted to put them into Odoo. I managed to get a dashboard run using Chart.js but d3.js is more complete for me. I loaded the d3.js but the charts aren't showing.
This is the d3.js javascript's I'm using. I resorted to pastebin because I don't know what else could I add for this issue. Please bear with me. But I don't really know why it is not showing...
